# PHP telegram API read group chat messages

Tags: php, database, api, telegram-bot

Is it possible to create a PHP script which allows me to receive telegram messages out of group chat. I am following a group channel on Telegram with my personal account. The messages I receive needs to be processed by PHP. I know it is possible to create a bot, but can a bot do this? Is it able to join a channel/group and read all new messages?

I cannot find an answer to do so.

For example I'm in telegram.me/thisgroup. All the messages needs to be received by PHP and in the end stored in a database. The database part is not hard, but receiving it is.

Does somebody know how to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible by using bot API. 
By default bots can't recive all messages. but you can change this setting.

here is the document about this: https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode

1. Create bot.
2. Change Privacy Mode of the Bot.
3. Add bot to group
4. Setup webhook to recive messages or use getUpdates method.
5. Store messages to your database.